# App shows error Manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I install the android studio just run the application it just showing this error iput the code in manifest and bulid gradle, please review it and give me simple solution thanky

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.co`enter code 
   here`m/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.customerdrawer"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <application    tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomerDrawer"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And this is build.gradle file

```
   plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 30
  buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.customerdrawer"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }

   buildTypes {
     release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard- 
  rules.pro'
     }
 }
  compileOptions {
     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 } 
  }

  dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
 }
```

I have other solutions as per given but nothing changes please Assist Thanks

Comment: Try changing the design support library to androidx design. Google it.

Comment: ok thanks i will check it